# printing from list of tuples without brackets and comma

Tags: python-3.x

From this list of tuples:

```
lst = [('abc',1), ...]
```

I want to print out

```
abc 1
```

I have tried

```
var = lst[0]
print (var[0], var[1])
```

Is there a direct way to print the desired result?

Another way is using for loop but I think it is completely useless clutter for this.

Comment: Your way is the most direct. Why do you consider a loop "useless clutter" if you do in fact want to loop over a sequence of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have many answers!
If you only want to print the first one, you can do:

```py
lst = [('abc',1),('efg',99)]
print(*lst[0]) # Output: abc 1
```

If you want to do that with each element of the list:

```py
lst = [('abc',1),('efg',99)]

for e in lst:
    print(*e)
```

Finally, if you want to print this tuple but still save it in a variable, you can do:

```py
lst = [('abc',1),('efg',99)]
print(*(var:=lst[0])) # Output: abc 1

print(var) # Output: ('abc', 1)
print(*var) # Output: abc 1
```